# In Rhino Mocks, how to stub a method using a null argument?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a method, canUserRead, which can handle a null argument as the user (because sometimes users are not logged in).

Now I want to create a stub whose behavior reflects that of the method. I tried:

```
IAccessRightsManager stubAccessRights = new 
    MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAccessRightsManager>(); 

// if there is no user logged in  
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(null, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(false);  //doesn't compile
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(null, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true); //doesn't compile
// if there is a user without confidentiality clearance logged in 
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(nonPrivilegedUser, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(false);  
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(nonPrivilegedUser, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true); 
// if there is a user with confidentiality clearance logged in 
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(privilegedUser, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(true);  
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(privilegedUser, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true);
```

This does not compile, because null is not of type IUser. And null doesn't have referential identity, so initializing a new IUser variable with null doesn't help.

So, how do I create a stub method which returns something sensible when passed a null argument?

Comment: What version do you use? Latest version from NuGet does not contain the *GenerateStub* method on *MocksRepository*.

Comment: @galenus I use Rhino Mocks 3.6 build 21, downloaded from the Rhino Mocks website (not trough NuGet). It was the current version when I downloaded it in February.

Comment: As I understand, Rhino hadn't been maintained until recently. It changed [this May](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/rhino-mocks). So you better update the library from NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IAccessRightsManager stubAccessRights = new 
    MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAccessRightsManager>(); 

stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead((IUser)null, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(false);  
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead((IUser)null, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest `Arg<T>.Is.Null`:

```
stubAccessRights
    .Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(Arg<IUser>.Is.Null, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(false);

stubAccessRights
    .Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(Arg<IUser>.Is.Null, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true);
```

Comment: I will accept galenus' solution, because it worked consistently. For some reason, Arg<IUser>.Is.Null sometimes caused an exception (but I may have used it improperly). Else it seems like a good solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `Arg<T>.Is.Anything` syntax

```
IAccessRightsManager stubAccessRights = new 
    MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAccessRightsManager>(); 

stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(Arg<IUser>.Is.Anything, confidentialDocument))
    .Return(false);  
stubAccessRights.Stub(ar => ar.canUserRead(Arg<IUser>.Is.Anything, nonConfidentialDocument))
    .Return(true);
```

Comment: If this was all my stub had to do, I guess it would work. But the stub also has to return true or false for logged in users, I suppose it won't work then? I will update the question with the other conditions. It is good to know about the Is.Anything syntax though, I can roll all cases for a non-confidential document into one

Comment: See the updated question. I want to have both a call with null and a call with a specific IUser. If I use Is.Anything for the null call, I assume that it will also cover the case in which I pass a specific IUser. Or does RhinoMocks only apply a more general match when there is no specific match defined?